# Drone.io Filter by Tag name

Tags: drone.io

So I'm doing a build with drone.io and I'm wondering if with the build/deploy/publish steps it is possible to do:

`when:
 tag: PRODUCTION`

Or something similar in the same way it is possible to do with branches.

If not is there anyway to use the $$DRONE_TAG variable to do this for you or is it necessary to manipulate the git hook somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter steps based on the hook event type:

```
when:
  event: tag
```

If you need to filter steps based on the tag name, this may be possible depending on which version control hosting provider you are using. If you are using GitHub, when drone processes a tag hook event, it sets the branch to `refs/tags/%s`. This means you can filter tags based on branch name:

```
when:
  event: tag
  branch: refs/tags/PRODUCTION
```

Comment: Any idea if GitLab does the same?

Comment: Adding this just for reference. In case of bitbucket it is just the tag name.
If the tag is `v0.0.1` then the branch will be `v0.0.1`. So we could do something like this `branch: v0.0.*`